# How to track null in Typescript with?

Tags: typescript

If you're using flags to determine if a function should continue or not, Typescript doesn't recognize the flag and thus can't null typecheck a variable. E.g.

```
const foo: null | number = null
if (foo === null) 
 return;

const bar: number = foo;
```

In the previous example, typescript knows that foo is not a null, so it's safe to assign. But in the following example:

```
const foo: number | null = null
let nullFlagOn = false;
if (foo === null) 
 nullFlagOn = true

if (nullFlagOn)
 return;

const bar: number = foo;
```

typescript won't be able to guess that `foo` is not null, so it'll complain. You can try the code [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/BQMwrgdgxgLglgewgAmASmQbwFDOVJAZxmRAQQC5kIwBbAIwFMAnZAH2rABsvkBeTj1zIujEjR4AxLgEMA5gHkUAkDK6FGAbmFwQqMgn58BErmmF5T0%20Uv7IYzMI2w69wK7MURzePMzFgzBDawgQQxMj0MsxUNAwsdgbaAL5o6EA)

Any solution or alternatives?

Comment: Nope, just use the check directly in the if, that is the only supported way

Comment: <strike>I've put your second example into the typescript playground, but it doesn't complain about this.</strike> EDIT: writing `const foo: number | null = 5` resulted in a number type. I guess you didn't intend that. Maybe you could update your example

Comment: Both of your snippets work when placed in a function. What is the error you're getting?

Comment: Please consider providing a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue you're seeing.  Right now [there is no error](https://tsplay.dev/ewezKN).

Comment: Thanks @jcalz for the feedback. I updated the snippet and added example.

Comment: No, you can't do this.  There is an issue, [microsoft/TypeScript#12184](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12184) asking for this but it would hurt compiler performance to do all the extra checks necessary to keep track of that.

Answer (score -2):

Typescript normally work with null

[Playground with your case](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/BQMwrgdgxgLglgewgAmASmQbwFDOVJAZxmQENkBeZCMAG1oG5dlmCJCFaBTAOloQDmwAOSlaAd1IBPQsLRNmcEMHIU11OrQwAnLjDDaICvGw7c%20gkRC4A3LtrlMAvmnRA) [www.typescriptlang.org](http://www.typescriptlang.org)

```
(function () {
  const a = null;
  
  console.log('always');

  if(a === null) return;

  console.log('never');
})()
```

Result:

```
[LOG]: "always"
```

Comment: I don't understand your answer, sorry.